Setting the return type of a custom namedtuple
I have a sample_config.json file with potentially an arbitrary number of the parameters. An example of the sample_config.json is as follows:
{
  "tableA_ID": "tableA.csv",
  "tableB_ID": "tableB.csv",
  "time_period" : 10,
  "start_date": "2024-07-01",
  "optimization_metric": "L1",
  "id": 353
}

In this case, there are 6 key values, but there could be arbitrarily many more. I have the following helper function to read in this json, as a custom namedtuple, with the resulting type named ConfigTuple.
import json
from collections import namedtuple
from pathlib import Path

def get_config_namedtuple(config_path: str | Path) -> ConfigTuple:
    config_path = Path(config_path)
    with open(f"{config_path}") as f:
        config = json.load(f)
        ConfigTuple = namedtuple("ConfigTuple", config)
    return ConfigTuple(**config)

This can be used successfully as follows:
config_path = Path("sample_config.json")
config = get_config_namedtuple(config_path=config_path)
# using the namedtuple
print(f"{config.tableB_ID=}")

This works, and prints "tableB.csv". However, the return type of the function -> ConfigTuple keeps throwing LSP errors, namely "ConfigTuple" is not defined.
This makes sense since we define it in the function body, not outside globally. Is there a way to elegant fix this issue, i.e., ensure that the return type ConfigTuple can be used, for a JSON object with an arbitrary number of keys?
I'd like for the type to be correctly respected in the return type of the function signature, and not just ignore the type error.

How could that possibly work? This is analysed statically, without knowing the content of the file. Probably a namedtuple isn't the right structure for arbitrary content at all, and a dict (that let you safely .get keys) is more suitable - just return config (if there's a minimal set of known keys, you could define them with a TypedDict).

@jonrsharpe - I understand the type declaration for the return type is not correct. I'm asking if there is a way to make this work, e.g. by creating a helper function which defines the ConfigTuple type in advance? The code as written above does work, but my point is to understand how to make the typing work somehow.

I take your point that the NamedTuple may not be ideal for arbitrary length content. However, I wanted to preserve immutability once the config was read in, as a safety check. The namedtuple also provides more readable accessing of key values, which is a nice bonus. Hence the purpose of investigating here.

What do you mean "in advance" here? Again, those types are analysed statically. If you know that the result is going to have e.g. a tableB_ID attribute you can define that with NamedTuple, but what you're doing is fundamentally unsafe if the JSON content is arbitrary.

Thanks @jonrsharpe, appreciate your insights. I see that for arbitrary JSON, this might actually be unsafe. By in advance I meant whether the type checker could acknowledge ConfigTuple before the function get_config_namedtuple is defined, somehow. But I understand that this is not reasonable to expect if the the JSON is of arbitrary length.

The type checker (at least any I've used, e.g. mypy) isn't going to go and introspect the JSON file and build and inject a ConfigTuple definition into your code prior to analysing it such that the analysis would succeed and you'd get type-safe access. That's not to say it couldn't be done, but it's outside the scope of every such tool I'm aware of. Safer would be to define an actual model (namedtuple or otherwise, e.g. using Pydantic) and ingest the JSON against that model so you get a clear signal if it mismatches at runtime.

Thanks again @jonrsharpe - this is great feedback. Appreciate it. If the keys are fixed, I will try to define the namedtuple up front, but if there are an arbitrary number, I'll just return the dict.

so, taking a step back, think of what you are asking here: how can I get my static analysis tool to recognize a type that I am creating dynamically at runtime? Do you see the issue?

@juanpa.arrivillaga - yep the issue is clear (per my comments above accepting the fact). Thank you for teaching and guiding me here. Note, my purpose was well-intentioned, I really did want the config to be read in and used as an immutable data structure, but appreciate the broader issue in this case.
